# Weird normal map baking

Tags: uv, normals, baking

I've looked to this problem all over the site and it's not been answered (or maybe i wasnt attentive enough) but the thing is what you can see on the pictures. Some weird artifacts appear both where the UV seams are and separately from them. Thank you.

**The weird artifacts**
[image]

**The normal map and settings**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to bake the model in different versions of Blender. Here's the results:

An old 2.93 alpha build: slightly better, still seeing other problems.

2.83 LTS: Works as expected.